# How to forward Assembly dependencies references?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a sample project which depends on `Assembly1.dll`. Everything is great except said assembly does not expose anything directly, instead it just a container that references multiple dependencies (modules). Now, I could reference them all, all 83, but that's ridiculous and what is more important - **the existing MSVS2017 solution somehow worked (as in on the creator machine) by referencing only head dependency i.e. Assembly1 and the rest of assemblies (which are in the same location as the base) somehow got resolved (through it?).**

The project file does not have anything special:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Assembly1">
      <HintPath>..\Libs\Assembly1.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.XML" />
```

How is this done? I tried to google extensively but because the search keywords are too generic I get 2bil results for "How to reference dependency" crap.

Comment: It’s not clear that there is even anything wrong. Are you getting some kind of error? At compile time or runtime? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the creator added those assemblies to Global Assembly Cache([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)) from where those references were loaded.

You may try to add those assemblies using `gacutil -i <assembly name>` command. More about it in [`Working with Assemblies and the Global Assembly Cache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/working-with-assemblies-and-the-gac).

Comment: I dont think that it is but it is a good workaround nonetheless, thanks